# Using negation in df.query()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am slicing a dataframe in several subsets. To do that I used query because more efficient in my case.

I translated this

```
df2=df1[(~df1['ColA'].isnull()) & (df1['colB'].isnull())]
```

in

```
df2=df1.query("(ColA==ColA) & (ColB != ColB)")
```

but how do I translate this using query?

```
df3=df1[~((~df1['ColA'].isnull()) & (df1['ColB'].isnull()))]
```

Comment: The following should actually work (can't test since there's no example data): `df1.query('~(ColA.notna() & ColB.isna())')`. Note: I use `isna` and `notna` since its more consistent with `dropna` and `fillna`

Comment: What is your rationale to replace the straighforward `colB.isnull()` by `colB != colB`? Looking at the result of `None != None` which is `False` (as opposed to `np.nan != np.nan` which is `True`) I'm not sure if both constructs are 100 % equivalent in *all* cases.

Comment: Well that's the solution that I found to handle the df.isnull() function. I am aware of the `pd.isnull()` with `engine="python"` but it was slower and I didn't know about that None case. Will using directly the pandas function by specifying the issue handle it ?

Answer (score 1):

Just need to change the condition like , logic reversed from and to or

```
df1.query("(ColA!=ColA) | (ColB == ColB)")
```

Comment: I thought about this solution as well but I stil don't know how to use negation for query :)